# Determine port in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to make some microservices with asp.net core (Web Api)
For service discovery I want use Consul where I must register the services via the HTTP API including IP and port.

My question is:
How can I know which port is used within in a service? Is there a way to determine the used port via code?

Comment: How would you register the API ?

Answer (score 8):

Yeah, Use `HttpContext.Connection.LocalPort` to get the local port that the server is listening on.

Comment: Hows it working, I can't see to access this property

Comment: Inside your controller action, use something like `this.HttpContext.Connection.LocalPort`