# Kestrel: get access to IP+port pair(s) it's listening on

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, kestrel-http-server

I need the listening IP+port pairs to be able to forward them through a NAT implementation. However, barring a request (which is when HttpContext becomes accessible), I'm not seeing an easy way of getting access to this information.

I noted that someone else had the same question on [Determine port in asp.net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41165303/determine-port-in-asp-net-core), but that went unanswered.

Anyone have a clue stick to hit me with? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `IWebHost` interface has a `ServerFeatures` property , which is an instance of `IFeatureCollection` . If you want to get the server address & port before a HttpContext created , you could retrieve them by :

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build();

    var serverAddresses = host.ServerFeatures.Get<IServerAddressesFeature>();

    // ... use serverAddresses as you like

    host.Run();
}
```

Note the serverAddresses here is the `Address:Port` listened by the `WebHost` , not by `IIS` or `nginx` .

Comment: Yeah, I just need details from Kestrel itself. I'll give this a try and get back to you tomorrow.